# Can't collect edr-log and store it in HDFS using nifi

Tags: hdfs, apache-nifi

1. I'm trying to collect the logs from EDR and store it in hdfs using NIFI using the following nifi dataflow: Its working well but the size of the stored file was so small though I combined records together

{the fist dataflow I created ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9AyX.png)

[configuration of listenUDP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWbu7.png)

2. I intended to merge records before do the compression but the merge process not receiving data from the listenUDP processor
3. I tried listenUDP record instead of listenUDP but it didn't listen to any data

[Second dataflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ysg4.png) 
[configuration of mergerecod processor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZv1B.png)

any suggested solution

suggested solution, what's wrong with what I did?